# Pseudocode for switch statement in c#

Tags: c#, switch-statement, pseudocode

How do I write the pseudocode for a switch (case) statement in C#?

```
switch (option)
{
    case 1:
        Console.Write("Enter First Number: ");
        num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter Second Number: ");
        num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        result = num1 + num2;
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        break;

    case 2:
        Console.Write("Enter First Number: ");
        num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter Second Number: ");
        num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        result = num1 - num2;
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        break;

    case 3:
        Console.Write("Enter First Number: ");
        num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter Second Number: ");
        num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        result = num1 * num2;
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        break;

    default:
        Console.WriteLine("\n Next time follow instructions. You can only choose numbers 1 - 4");
        break;
}
```

Comment: You repeat a ton of code here, wouldnt it make more sense to encapsulate the only thing that changes (the math operation) inside the switch statement and do the rest outside of that scope?

Comment: Are you asking "how do I describe this existing code in some sort of pseudo code?"  Each case is basically "Ask the user for two numbers and return the sum/difference/product/division-of as a result".  Do you want something more explicit?  For what it's worth, your code would be easier to read if you used an enum rather than an integer as your "option".  Never underestimate the value of "easy to read" code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I'm just learning to program and I missed the class where they wrote the pseudocode for the above c# code. What I need is the pseudocode for the above c# code.

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking for. If you missed a class you should ask your professor or TA.

Comment: "What I need is the pseudocode for the above c# code", so to be clear, you need us to "un-codify" the above code?  Psudo code: switch (something) {case "something you want": //do something break;}

Comment: Hi @iPreach, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I think what the above comments are trying to say is that it's a little difficult to answer your question. This is because [pseudocode (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) has no set-in-stone definition. There are many possible ways, ranging from short and sweet to long and detailed, to describe the above code. There is not **a** pseudocode version of any code, but many possible ones. The right thing to do might be to read up on pseudocode a bit, and look up some examples of code accompanied by good and bad pseudocode versions of itself

Comment: @iPreach I see you changed your mark answer for the "pseudocode" . Maybe you can give some valueble feedback, why you choosed the other "pseudocode".

Comment: Hey @Llazar, I think I made an error in ticking it. What I really wanted to do was to say it was useful but I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Answer (score 2):

So, if I was going to write this, I'd start with an enumerated type for the operations:

```
public enum ArithmeticOperation
{
    Add,
    Subtract,
    Multiply,
    Divide,
}
```

I'd write a little helper function:

```
 private static string ShowEnumOptions<T>() where T : struct
 {
     if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
     {
         throw new ArgumentException($"Type: {typeof(T).ToString()} must be an enumerated type");
     }

     var options = Enum.GetNames(typeof(T));
     return string.Join("/", options);
 }
```

*(the newest version of C# (which I don't use yet) allows a System.Enum constraint on a generic type parameter which would simplify this)*

Then I'd write my main program to look like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        ArithmeticOperation operation = default(ArithmeticOperation);
        var goodOperation = false;
        while (!goodOperation)
        {
            Console.Write(
                $"Enter operation (one of [{ShowEnumOptions<ArithmeticOperation>()}] or \"Quit\"): ");
            var response = Console.ReadLine();
            if (string.Equals(response, "Quit", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return; //quit the app
            }

            if (Enum.TryParse<ArithmeticOperation>(response, true, out operation))
            {
                goodOperation = true;
            }
        }

        double value1 = 0.0;
        double value2 = 0.0;        //initialize them to keep the compiler happy
        var goodDouble = false;
        while (!goodDouble)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the first number: ");
            var response = Console.ReadLine();
            if (double.TryParse(response, out value1))
            {
                goodDouble = true;
            }
        }
        goodDouble = false;
        while (!goodDouble)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the second number: ");
            var response = Console.ReadLine();
            if (double.TryParse(response, out value2))
            {
                goodDouble = true;
            }
        }

        //ok, got an operation and two numbers

        double result = 0.0;
        switch (operation)
        {
            case ArithmeticOperation.Add:
                result = value1 + value2;
                break;
            case ArithmeticOperation.Subtract:
                result = value1 - value2;
                break;
            case ArithmeticOperation.Multiply:
                result = value1 * value2;
                break;
            case ArithmeticOperation.Divide:
                if (value2 == 0.0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Division by zero is invalid");
                    result = double.NaN;   //NaN means "not a number"
                    break;
                }
                result = value1 / value2;
                break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Result is {result}");
    }
}
```

Note that I check all input for validity.  Always assume your users will enter bad data.  Also note that I check my double for equality with zero.  Checking for floating point equality is usually a bad idea, but it's the right thing to do here.

Then, as pseudo code, all I'd write would be:

```
 // Get the operation (one of add/subtract/multiply or divide) - or allow the user to quit
 // Get each of value1 and value2 as doubles
 // Based on the operation, calculate the result (pay attention to division by zero)
 // Show the result
 // Loop back and let the user try again (or quit)
```

Comment: I have no clue what this is. This is beyond my capacity at this time. Could you break it down please?

Comment: An `enum` is made up of a set of symbols (like `Add`).  They are mapped to integers (so `Add` is actually 0, etc).  The helper function takes those symbols and makes a string that looks like `Add/Subtract/Multiply/Divide`.  The rest of it follows the pseudo-code.  Get a debugger and step through the code to see what it does.  `Double.TryParse` and `Enum.TryParse` try to parse a string into the correct type.  They return true/false based on whether the parsing was successful, and the value in the `out` parameter. The 'true' in `Enum.TryParse` says "Ignore case"

Comment: Oh, and I loop around everything.  If the user makes a mistake, I let him try again.  And, when the operation is finished, I let him try again until he says `Quit`.  I track whether the user entered good input with the `goodOperation` and `goodDouble` variables.  The `while` loops loop until they are good.  The outer `while` loop loops forever (`while(true)` means "loop forever").

Comment: By the way, I'm not kidding about stepping through this in a debugger.  The best way to learn to code is to step through someone else's (hopefully) good/working code.

Comment: By the way, feel free to get rid of the `if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)` test in the `ShowEnumOptions` function.  It will never fire in this case.  You might want to try to figure out what it does though (with documentation and debugging/stepping)

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode is basically writing what you're trying to do in comments.  What your professor was probably trying to teach you is to make a bunch of comments to plan out the structure of your code, and then write your code.  What you have above is already functional code. At the risk of answering your homework question, I'd say it goes something like this:

```
switch(option)
{
    case 1:
        //do something
        break;
    case 2:
        //do something else
        break;
    default:
        //what to do if none of the cases are met
        break;
}
```

Comment: Sorry guys, but that is not what I am looking for. Pseudocode, as I have been taught, looks like this:
`code`
START
 DEFINE hour, mins, secs as real;
 PRINT “Please enter the amount of hours: ”;
 READ hour;
 mins = hour * 60;
 secs = mins * 60;
 IF hour >= 1 THEN
 PRINT hour, “hour(s) is equivalent to” mins, “minute(s).”;
 PRINT hour, “hour(s) is equivalent to” secs, “second(s).”;
 ELSE
 PRINT “I am sorry; this operation is absurd>”;
 END IF
STOP
`code`

Comment: @iPreach Pseudocode, by it's very nature, does not have rigid rules for what is and is not acceptable.  The whole *point* of pseudocode is to use it to express an idea that is similar to code without having any of the strict rules that come with using *actual* code, as such, there are *lots* of different forms it can take.

Comment: My pseudo code (below, on my answer, starting with _Get the operation (one of add/subtract/multiply or divide)_) is perfectly good "pseudo code" - at least to me.  Your teacher's "pseudo code" is more of a formal language.  If you need to follow his/her standard, then you get to learn his/her language.  It's not something anyone who hasn't been one of his students would know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean with pseudocode but this code is less repetitive:

```
double result = 0;
Console.Write("Enter First Number: ");
double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Enter Second Number: ");
double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Enter a number from 1 to 3");
string input = Console.ReadLine();

switch (input) {

    case "1" : 
        result = num1 + num2;
        break;
    case "2":
        result = num1 - num2;
        break;
    case "3":
        result = num1 * num2;
        break;  
    default:
    Console.WriteLine("\n Next time follow instructions. You can only choose numbers 1 - 4");
    break;

}
Console.WriteLine("Result = " + result);
```

Comment: Not what I was looking for, but this is helpful in another way.
Help me to understand please:

Comment: Not what I was looking for, but this is helpful in another way.
Help me to understand please:

1. why double result = 0; and not double result;
2. why Console.WriteLine("Result = " + result); and not Console.WriteLine("Result = ", result);
3. Why not define num1 and num2 at the same time as result?
4. Do you need quotation marks around the number in the case, eg. case "1"....?

Comment: I suggest you to read a book or read C# docs to understand the basic of programming in C#. First you need to initializes the value like the `result`. Second the `WriteLine` is a method of `Console` class and in this case has a parameter as string.

Comment: By the way, my pseudo code (on my answer) matches this code - it's basically the same, but mine checks the user's inputs and is (I know you won't agree initially) easier to read.  Your questions: "why result = 0.0;" well, you need to have result set to something when you get to the last line, and since there are paths that don't set it, it needs to be initialized.  Why the quotes around "1", etc.  Well, you didn't show us what you got from the users, but, it comes in as a string, so why bother converting it to an int.

Comment: Thanks @Flydog57 for completed my answer. Upvote to you.